# Why can I not set an integer equal to another integer inside a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, integer

I currently have the code as follows, its function is explained below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    Scanner Kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int spacesLn = 0;
    int numSaver = 0;
    int numAst;

    System.out.println("Enter The Number of Asterics You Would Like To Create");
    numAst = Kb.nextInt();


    for(int Spaces = 0; Spaces <= numAst; Spaces++)
    {
        while(spacesLn < 0)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
            spacesLn++;

        }
        numSaver--;
        spacesLn = numSaver;
        System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println("");
    }   
  }
}
```

This program asks for a number then makes a diagonal line of asterisks equal to that number in the following fashion: line one - zero spaces, followed by an asterisk, line two - one space, followed by an asterisk, etc. Strictly speaking the function of the code is slightly irrelevant to my question, but there it is anyways. It works perfectly. Despite this, I decided that I wanted to make the while loop that is nested in the for loop, into a for loop. I changed the code containing the loops to as follows, and I deleted the declaration of the variable spacesLn.

```
for(int Spaces = 0; Spaces <= numAst; Spaces++)
    {
        for(int spacesLn = 0; spacesLn < 0; spacesLn++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        numSaver--;
        spacesLn = numSaver;
        System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println("");

    }
```

Now when I run this it gives me this error:

```
Main.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
            spacesLn = numSaver;
            ^
  symbol:   variable spacesLn
  location: class Main
1 error

exit status 1
```

I'm very confused by this error, I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing incorrectly. Although I can assume that my error will be inevitably stupid on my part I just feel like I've dotted my "i"s and crossed my "t"s.

Please if anyone could help me understand my error I would be extremely grateful. Many thanks in advance, Max.

Comment: You define `spacesLn` inside your inner for loop. It's not available outside of it.

Comment: OH, so that would be why I was using a while loop in the first place? This is older code I am revisiting by the way.

Comment: Well, I don't know why you were using a while loop. You are not required to define the variable in your loop though. You can choose to define it before the loop and just leave the initialization empty. (`for(; spacesLn < 0; spacesLn++)`)

Comment: @Ivar I'm going to be honest I was not aware that with a for loop you could just use a semicolon, instead of initializing a variable. Thank you, if you would like me to mark your answer correct just put it as in an answer and submit it, I will selected it as correct over the others because you explained much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable `spacesLn` goes out of scope after the for-loop terminates.

If you want to use it after, declare it before the for-loop.

```
int spacesLn;

for(spacesLn = 0; spacesLn < 0; spacesLn++) {
    System.out.print(" ");
}

numSaver--;
spacesLn = numSaver;
```

Comment: Not too sure what you are trying to with that but that for loop will never even be entered with that end condition, since `spacesLN` is never < 0. @Maximus

Comment: @luckydog32 The first time that for loop in not entered, but after that first time spacesLn becomes a negative. It isn't entered the first time because the first asterisk should only have an asterisk no space.

Comment: @Maximus spacesLn will always be 0 at the start of each loop because you are setting it to 0 at the start of each loop.

Comment: @luckydog32 Are you aware of how for loops work????? If they worked like you say they did, this code wouldn't print 1 - 100:                          `class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
      System.out.println(i);
  }
}`

Comment: @Maximus Yes. Let me rephrase. You are setting `spacesLn` to 0 each time you get to your for loop block. So it won't iterate.

Comment: No that will print the numbers between 0 and 100, regardless, right now you have the equivalent of `for(int i = 0; i < 0; i++)`. @Maximus

Comment: @luckydog32 Yes, that is supposed to happen, the code works, I assure you.

Comment: By "that" I meant you prior comment, and I accidentally said 1 - 100.

Comment: @luckydog32, if you are correct, then why does the code function as intended?

Comment: @Maximus You are setting the value of `int spacesLn = 0` and then immediately checking if `spacesLn < 0` which is always false, since you just set it to 0, hence you will never enter the loop. Just try it out, you will see whats going on since you seem to not believe me.

Comment: I have no idea what your talking about, if you have a way to run this, please do, and tell me how this doesn't work.     import java.util.Scanner; class Main { public static void main(String[] args) { Scanner Kb = new Scanner(System.in); int spaceLn= 0; int numSaver = 0; int numAst; System.out.println("Enter The Number of Asterics You Would Like To Create"); numAst = Kb.nextInt(); for(int Spaces = 0; Spaces <= numAst; Spaces++) { for(; spaceLn< 0; spaceLn++) { System.out.print(" "); } numSaver--; spaceLn= numSaver; System.out.print("*"); System.out.println(""); } } }

Comment: @Maximus `for(; spaceLn< 0; spaceLn++)`, You changed the code though? It works fine if you don't set it to 0 first, yes, that was the point. I'm going to move on with my life now if that's ok.

Comment: Oh shoot. The code in my question is an old version. Crap. Well great arguing with you, thanks for your help. @luckydog32

Answer (score 0):

*"and I deleted the declaration of the variable spacesLn."*

You need to declare the variable, that's why it cannot find symbol.  You use it as the iterator in your for loop, but that makes it available only inside your for loop.  When it gets to

```
spacesLn=numSaver;
```

spacesLn no longer exists.

Also take a close look at

```
for(int spacesLn = 0; spacesLn < 0; spacesLn++)
```

You're saying it goes from zero up to less than zero...so basically never.

Answer (score 0):

In java methods or loop variables are not accessible outside of that ,you declared  `int spacesLn = 0` in for loop.

> In this case you can access spacesLn only within for loop not outside that.

if you want to use that spacesLn outside for loop declare it as class variable like you have done in while loop example.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

class Main
{

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
Scanner Kb = new Scanner(System.in);
int spacesLn = 0;
int numSaver = 0;
int numAst;

System.out.println("Enter The Number of Asterics You Would Like To Create");
numAst = Kb.nextInt();


for(int Spaces = 0; Spaces <= numAst; Spaces++)
{
   for(spacesLn ; spacesLn < 0; spacesLn++) {
      System.out.print(" ");
    }

    numSaver--;
    spacesLn = numSaver;
    System.out.print("*");
    System.out.println("");
 }
 }
}`
```